# mail() function is not working in cakephp 2

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am using mail() function in cakephp 2 to send the mail in the server. The mail is not delivered.

PHP - 5.6

Code:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
$headers.= "From: " . $from . "\n"; 
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
 echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

phpinfo screenshot below:
[image]

There is no error message is showing. The mail sending status is true. but mail is not receiving.

Comment: CakePHP doesn't interfere with PHP's native `mail()` function in any way whatsoever. If it's not working, then that's up to your PHP config / sendmail target.

Comment: @ndm Thanks for the response. What kind of setup need to be done ? i have attachment of phpinfo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on your local machine , it won't work until you configure your local mail server. Most cpanels support php mail() function , but you need manual configuration for sendmail on your local machine / LAMP stack / vps server.

Comment: thanks for the response. i am checking this mail functionality in the server not in local machine. any other suggestions?